# A Product Page with dynamic variants without using Commerce

Tags: nodes, commerce, panels, theming

I have a page that is product page for an offline product. This product will never be sold through the website, so the [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module would be serious overkill I think. There are some features of the the product pages I've seen possible in Commerce that I need though. Like product colors.

For what I'm working on, the product model has different builds, **(see the wireframe image)** and each build has different color options. I need to be able to toggle back and for between color options for a build, and build options for the model.

I would like the model to be all one content type. There are common elements in the model that should stay the same no matter what the build, but items that are build specific that should update when a build is clicked. I'm  still trying to figure out the best way to structure the content type fields and such too.

I'm sure someone has had a similar need and I'm looking for tips in the right direction for the content type and the display. Since everything is part of the same content type, I figured I'd use a specific layout and use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) to stitch it together, especially since I have related content to the model below the product.

Here are my direct questions:
How would I go about segmenting the different build levels in the same content type?

What would be the best way to pull all this back into a display and have the right areas work to allow the large image of the product be able to be switched when the color links are actioned and then have all the right parts change when a different build is selected?

[image: Wireframe for the Product Page]

Comment: So since I originally posted this, I've stumbled across [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) which seems like it could do it, or since this is limited to one content type, maybe just some serious `.tpl` work is in order.

Honestly at this point, throwing a bunch of modules at the problem seems like the wrong solution, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

As the user eluded, [display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or perhaps [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) would be the go-to way to dealing with customized multi-column content type displays. Often on commerce sites, the [quick tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module is used to display tabbed product information.